# Как доработать код?

Tags: python

Определите максимальное количество идущих подряд символов, среди которых нет сочетания стоящих рядом букв P и R(в любом порядке)

```
f=open("24-157.txt")
#s=f.readline()
s='TROPERGOERPPRDGGDF'
s=s.replace("PR","1")
s=s.replace("RP","1")
max_=cnt=0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i]!='1':
        cnt+=1
        max_=max(max_,cnt)
    else:
        cnt=0
print(max_)
```

на примере все работает, а с файлом выдает неправильный ответ

[ссылка на файл](https://yadi.sk/d/HjEdOimPptVVyA)

Comment: Любопытно, а если регуляркой посчитать? `import re` `s=s.replace("PR", "1")` `s=s.replace("RP", "1")` `print(len(max(re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', s), key=len)))`

Comment: тоже неверно пишет

Comment: @gil9red кажется по времени с большими данными регулярка будет плоха, но это не точно

Comment: Там нет примера входных данных и ожидаемого результата?

Comment: @Dmitry, вместо findall можно использовать finditer, тогда меньше будет занимать в памяти :)

Comment: @gil9red нет, но что вашим способом и моим одинаковый ответ - 2938

Comment: Неожиданно сложная задача.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как ваш код обработает строку `'PRAPR'`? Первый `replace` превратит её в `'1A1'`, второй оставит строку неизменной. Затем вы отыщете самую длинную последовательность символов без единиц. Ответом будет единица.

Правильный ответ в этом примере - тройка (`'RAP'`). Алгоритмическая ошибка.

Бежим по строке, поддерживаем самую большую длину строки без `PR` и `RP` которая завершается в текущей позиции (`max_length_ending_here`). Если последняя пара "хорошая", увеличиваем длину на единицу,  иначе сбрасываем в единицу:

```
def max_lengths(s):
    max_length_ending_here = 0
    last_char = ''
    yield max_length_ending_here
    for c in s:
        if (c == 'P' and last_char == 'R') or (c == 'R' and last_char == 'P'):
            max_length_ending_here = 1
        else:
            max_length_ending_here += 1
        last_char = c
        yield max_length_ending_here


with open('24-157.txt') as f:
    s = f.readline()
print(max(max_lengths(s)))
```

> ```
> $ python max-length-no-pr-rp.py 
> 2940
> ```

Решение без циклов. Найдём все сочетания `RP`, `PR` и вставим между ними пробелы. Разобьём строку на слова, выберем самое длинное слово:

```
with open('24-157.txt') as f:
    s = f.readline()
print(max(
    map(len, s.replace('RP', 'R P').replace('PR', 'P R').split()),
    default=0
))
```

**P.S.** Это новый вариант ответа, который существенно исправлен.

Comment: исправил : `s=s.replace("P","1")
s=s.replace("R","1")`
выдает ответ 166, но он тоже неверный

Comment: На `'APPB'` новый вариант выдаст единицу. А должна быть четверка.

Comment: @НикитаЛосев Да в принципе сам подход с заменой неправильный